# Hide UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am creating many `UIImageview` using for loop like a wallpaper app. And i am adding `UIActivityIndicatorView` to each `UIImageview`. `UIImageview` load image from the webservice. when the image is loaded to the `UIImageview` that time the `UIActivityIndicatorView` of this `UIImageview` is hide.

I am give tag of both `UIImageview` and `UIActivityIndicatorView`.

Please tell me how do this.

Comment: after assigning image to image view hide the indicator.

Comment: put some code and show where your getting problem?

Comment: You can use the https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView for the same functionality

Comment: @AnilPrasad when i am assigning image ti image view and then hide the indicator that time all the indicator is also hide but some image view does not load the image from the webservice.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a completion block for the image fetching.

```
dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_async(q, ^{

    // Fetch the image from the server
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    // Add activity indicatory to image view 
    [imageview addSubview:activityIndicator];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{                 
       imageview.image = img;

      // After finishing image loading remove activity indicator
      [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
      [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a reference to an instance of `UIActivityIndicatorView`, just remove it from `superView`:

```
   [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
   [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
```